Understanding why sound channels swap when looping sound
I am writing a custom audio mixer in C++ which uses signed 16-bit PCM, 44100hz sample rate and 2 channels.
The problem that I'm facing is that whenever I need to loop sounds (that is, whenever I reach the end of the PCM buffer), I reset to the beginning by setting the sample index to 0, but, I noticed when playing a stereo sound with only 1 channel audible, the sound channels get swapped for some reason upon loop. The left samples actually play on the right, and right is on the left. They constantly swap every time it loops!
Code:
// this is called continuously in the audio thread:
if (BuffersPlaying() < MAX_SOUND_BUFFERS /* 2 */)
 for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES_PER_BUFFER /* 1024 */ * NUM_CHANNELS; ++i)
 {
     int mixedSamples = 0;
     for (size_t k = 0; k < sounds.size(); ++k)
     {
         Sound* sound = sounds[k];
         if (!sound->playing)
             continue;

         uint pcmSize = waveBuffers[sound->waveIndex].size / sizeof(int16);
         int16* pcmData = waveBuffers[sound->waveIndex].data;

         if (sound->sampleIndex < (int)pcmSize)
         {
             mixedSamples += (int)(pcmData[sound->sampleIndex] * soundsVolume);
             sound->sampleIndex++;
         }
         else if (sound->loop)
         {
             sound->sampleIndex = 0;

             mixedSamples += (int)(pcmData[sound->sampleIndex] * soundsVolume);
         }
         else
         {
             sound->playing = false;
             sound->sampleIndex = 0;
         }
     }
     soundBuffers[currentBuffer][i] = (int16)std::clamp((int)(mixedSamples * audioVolume), -32768, 32767);
}
QueueCurrentBuffer(); // uploads the current audio buffers for the audio API to play
currentBuffer++;
currentBuffer %= MAX_SOUND_BUFFERS;

However, I noticed that in else if (sound->loop), if I set sound->sampleIndex to NUM_CHANNELS - 1 rather than 0, this actually fixes it, but I don't understand why. Why is this?
I am using XAudio2 to play back the sound buffers.

Didn't read the code, but based on described symptom, looks like error "of by one" sample. Note if you will have not even number of samples (one per channel), then after a looping channels will be swapped.

Just out of curiosity, why are you writing a mixer when that's basically what XAudio2 does?

@Chuck Walbourn Just for convenience really. It's so I don't have to keep rewriting audio code for each audio API I need to support. By mixing it myself, all I have to do is submit the already-mixed audio packets to the audio API and that's it!

Another benefit is that this makes it so that audio will always sound the same regardless of the audio API used, I don't need to add extra code to balance the APIs. For example, OpenAL or XAudio2 might handle volume differently, where 0.1 could be near silent on OpenAL, but just a little quiet on XAudio2.

If you do your own mixing and source-rate conversion, then you should just output directly to WASAPI instead. The value of XAudio2 is as a high-quality real-time mixer. That said, a home-rolled mixer is likely to have a lot of performance impacts rather than using the API provided by the platform.
